# onConfigurationChanged is not called

Tags: android

Why is the onConfigurationChanged override method not called when i switch orientation ( ctrl+F11 ) in emulator.

```
public class HelloSample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);                
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        System.out.println("Change in Orientation");
    }

}
```

in manifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".HelloSample"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a real device, emulator doesn't support.